# Tag synonyms for context free languages

Tags: support, status-completed

The tags "context-free" and "context-free-languages" are clear synonyms. Could somebody with the appropriate reputation (2.5k+) please do the deed?

As a side issue/rant, it's annoying that options aren't even visible if you don't have enough reputation. It took me a long time to find out that the reason I couldn't directly suggest these as synonyms was because I don't have enough reputation, not because I was looking in the wrong place. The interface would be much more intuitive if the link to create new synonyms was visible but produced an error message. And why on earth does such a simple operation require so much reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't had to merge tags in a while: there's a standard procedure for doing this and I'll post a note on meta about that. As regards your other questions, I agree. It used to be the case that clicking on your reputation brought you to a page with a list of capabilities you had and what progress you had made towards the remaining. But that doesn't work any more.

As for why the levels are chosen that way, I think a lot of these thresholds were based on numbers for stackoverflow, and the SE gods have consistently refused to entertain the idea that different communities might need different natural thresholds.

Update: apparently with my AMP I can just create the synonym, and have done so.

Comment: I don't think they are synonym, e.g. CFG.